# can't include javascript (401 error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, get

There is a password on the domain which is set up with apache:

```
<Directory "dirname goes here">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "filename goes here"
  Require valid-user

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

index.html has this in it:

```
<script src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

index2.html has this in it:

```
<script src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Only on index2.html do I get this error in the chrome console:

`GET http://example.com/page/js/jquery.min.map 401 (Authorization Required)`

index.html works fine.

- What is `jquery.min.map`?
- Why am I getting a 401 error?

Comment: it's a source map file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Google Chrome?

1. Open your inspector element
2. Go to setting (on the top-right corner)
3. Uncheck Enable JavaScript source maps

Try

Comment: glad to help other person, I have spent more than an hour with this problem @collapsar

Comment: how do I prevent this error for users of my site that don't know to do this?

Comment: Usually  users hasn't active the inspector panel @bvpx

Comment: It is not exactly solution, more of workaround.  Problem still exist when requesting .min.map file.  Proper solution would probably involve some authentication or mime setting of webserver, but I have hard time to find that kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem today where I added some files to my project and then whenever I tried to access them I got a 401.

The thing that worked for me was deleting the added files and making sure I was copying and pasting them into my project rather than moving them from one directory to another. For whatever reason when I moved files it changed the security settings on the files and copying/pasting them enabled the settings to work.

I wish I knew why this happened, but this was my fix and hopefully helps anyone else coming by through Google.